# Google Script - How Can I Append Document Images Together?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've got the following chunk of code that is used to append documents together. It works fine, but whenever it attempts to append documents that contain images, it throws the exception "Action not allowed." Ideas as to why are appreciated.

```
var docIDs = destFolder.getFiles();
  while (docIDs.hasNext()) {
  var file = docIDs.next();
    list.push(file.getId());
}
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(list[0]);
  var body = baseDoc.getActiveSection();

  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; ++i ) {
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(list[i]).getActiveSection();
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
      var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();                                      
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE )
        body.appendImage(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK )
        body.appendPageBreak(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
        body.appendParagraph(element);

  }
  }
```

Edit: The exact line throwing the error is

```
else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
        body.appendParagraph(element);
```

The documents I'm attempting to append together are simple Google DOCs containing a few images.

Comment: Which is the line that gives you this error? Can you provide sample docs that would reproduce the issue?